# Mongodb update and insert data at the same time | upsert, react.js, meteor.js

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor, nosql, upsert

I'm trying to update questions if the questions already exist, and insert new questions if a user adds new questions.

```
const onSave = () => {
    if (creating) {
      // ・・ when you create a new questions, this runs
    } else if (editing) {
      // when you edit questions, this runs
      questions.forEach((question) => {
        Measures.update(
          { _id: question._id },
          {
            $set: {
              title: question.text,
              type:
                question.type === QuestionType.SHORT_ANSWER
                  ? MeasureType.TEXT
                  : MeasureType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
              typeOptions: { frequency },
              shortCodeOptions: {},
              entity: System.getCurrentEntity()
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
};
```

Right now, I just `Measures.update()` to update questions.
But I would like to not only update but also insert new questions into Measures collection if they are just added.

I looked the mongodb document [upsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/) but need a little more help.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/upsert/

I tried this but got an error saying "Mesures.updateMany() is not a function"

```
  Measures.updateMany(
    {_id: question._id},
    {
      $set: {
        title: question.text,
        type:
          question.type === QuestionType.SHORT_ANSWER
            ? MeasureType.TEXT
            : MeasureType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE,
        typeOptions: {frequency},
        shortCodeOptions: {},
        entity: System.getCurrentEntity(),
      },
    },
   {upsert: true},
  );
```

mongodb version  `5.0.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong documentation. Meteor collections are *not* mongodb-driver collections. You want to use https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert, i.e., just replace `update` with `upsert` (no options required).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm happy if you could take a look at [my new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031053/meteor-js-upsert-is-not-working-but-not-seeing-any-error-in-both-console-and-ter) with meteor if possible. Thanks